# Post tweet using fabric

Tags: android, twitter, tweets, twitter-fabric

I’m trying to share some informations on twitter from my android application. This is the scenario: If the user is authenticated, the application must post directly the tweet. If not, the user must login then the application has to share the tweet. For the share, this is my code:

```
   TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
 StatusesService statusesService = Twitter.getApiClient(session).getStatusesService();         
statusesService.update(message, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

But how can I check the session then redirect the user to the login screen if he is disconnected? And how can I immediately post the tweet if the login is succesful?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the session is null to know if user had login (there is no active session if no success result had been obtain or you directly set session).
About post a tweet directly after user succesful login - you just answer your own question: just do it in success method of callback interface.
check [this link](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter) and sorry for my english )